# View document where objects are serialized

Tags: java, serialization

I am writing a program where objects are serialized to a document called "Books.ser"

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Books.ser");
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    os.writeObject(shelf.book[i]);
}
os.close();
```

Is there a way to open up and view this document?
If not I just wanted to know if Java serializes objects that haven't been initialized yet. (null)

Comment: Yes, java will serialize nulls. When you read the object, cast it back to it's original form so you can interact with it. An easy way to check if you're writing nulls is to check if the variables contain objects before you write

Comment: Instead of serializing all the elements of an array you can serialize the array (which will serialize it's elements)

Comment: Just to confirm, when I serialize objects,their variables are serialized as well right? For instance if there was: String dueDate would shelf.book[i].dueDate be serialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the opposite loop should do.

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("Books.ser");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    Object o = os.readObject();
    // Do something with o - e.g. add to a List
}

ois.close();
```

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

> An ObjectOutputStream writes primitive data types and graphs of Java objects to an OutputStream. The objects can be read (reconstituted) using an ObjectInputStream. Persistent storage of objects can be accomplished by using a file for the stream.

So, basically you write primitives (e.g. `writeInt`) or objects (`writeObject`) with the `ObjectOutputStream` and then you read them back using the `ObjectInputStream` with the corresponding `read`-methods.

If the OutputStream knows the type of the Object that is to be serialized it **also works with null values**. E.g.

```
public static class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private final String content;

    public MyClass(final String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}

@Test
public void testWriteObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    MyClass nullInstance = null;
    MyClass notNullInstance = new MyClass("This content is not null");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)) {
        os.writeObject(nullInstance);
        os.writeObject(notNullInstance);
    }

    try (ObjectInputStream is = 
                 new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()))) {

        MyClass shouldBeNull = (MyClass) is.readObject();
        MyClass shouldNotBeNull = (MyClass) is.readObject();

        Assert.assertNull(shouldBeNull);
        Assert.assertNotNull(shouldNotBeNull);

        // Attributes are serialized too
        Assert.assertEquals("This content is not null", shouldNotBeNull.getContent());
    }
}
```

When using the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` classes it is recommended to use the try-with-resources construct (from Java 7).

```
try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Books.ser"))) {
    // loop and serialize...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah I did all that. I'm just wondering if Java serializes and then deserializes objects that haven't been initialized yet (null).

Comment: @noobProgrammer - gotcha! I updated the answer to provide a more detailed answer. Attributes are also serialized/deserialized, nulls are handled (see the provided test case).